# Unable to get data using Angular Http Client ( Angular 7 )

Tags: angular, typescript, api, angular-httpclient

I have recently started working on angular 7. I am getting a really basic issue with getting the data using http client. Looks like the code calls the rest services but the response body is always empty. I checked the IE developers tool and I can see the request has been made, but it always returns an empty response.

I have copied the request URL from the developers tool and tried in Fiddler and that's working and returning the data. Service is returning an array of Objects.

Data Service:

```
export class DataService {

   // Define API
   apiURL = 'https://localhost:5001/api/';

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   /*========================================
     CRUD Methods for consuming RESTful API
   =========================================*/

  public getAll(actionUrl: string): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

    return this.http.get(this.apiURL + actionUrl, { headers: headers });
  }
}
```

Component:

```
 public getData() {
    let actionUrl: string = 'Pizza';
    this.dataService
    .getAll(actionUrl)
    .subscribe((data: any) =>  {
      console.log(data)
    },
    error => (error: any) => {
      console.log("Error");
    });
    console.log("End");
  }
```

I used the type 'any' to make it generic. Otherwise I have to write the same code for each resource.
I have put the break point but it never go inside the "subscribe" or "error" method. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are using https on localhost, do you have ssl configured locally ? What is the response code from your API when you try to call it from another client like Postman ?

Comment: It's working in Fiddler but not in Postman. It is throwing an error: Could not get any response. Looks like it's an issue of certificate.

Comment: Is a http call working ?

Comment: Note that you should use an interceptor for this, then you don't have to trade away typings: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses. Your data service is a bit pointless right now.

Comment: I have configured the certificate and it's working in postman but now I am seeing a CORS error. Thank you @Stanislasdrg